# Pytorch Autograd: what does runtime error "grad can be implicitly created only for scalar outputs" mean

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, pytorch, autograd, automatic-differentiation

I am trying to understand Pytorch autograd in depth; I would like to observe the gradient of a simple tensor after going through a sigmoid function as below:

```
import torch
from torch import autograd 

D = torch.arange(-8, 8, 0.1, requires_grad=True)

with autograd.set_grad_enabled(True):
    S = D.sigmoid()
S.backward()
```

My goal is to get D.grad() but even before calling it I get the runtime error:

```
RuntimeError: grad can be implicitly created only for scalar outputs
```

I see another [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52317407/pytorch-autograd-grad-can-be-implicitly-created-only-for-scalar-outputs) with similar question but the answer over there is not applied to my question.  Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The error means you can only run `.backward` (with no arguments) on a unitary/scalar tensor. I.e. a tensor with a single element.

For example, you could do

```
T = torch.sum(S)
T.backward()
```

since `T` would be a scalar output.

I posted some more information on using pytorch to compute derivatives of tensors in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57261254/using-automatic-differentiation-libraries-to-compute-partial-derivatives-of-an-a/57569121#57569121).

Comment: @jodag- Thanks for the answer