# How to find partial derivative in pytorch

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytorch, differential-equations

I have a model `u(x,t)` with layers `2X50`, then `50X50`, and `50X1`.

I train the model with input `x,t` of size `[100,2]`. In the final layer I get `u` and now I want to differentiate it w.r.t to `x` and `t` and double differentiate w.r.t to `x`.  How do I do this in PyTorch?

Answer (score 4):

You can use PyTorch's [autograd engine](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/blitz/autograd_tutorial.html) like so:

```py
import torch

x = torch.randn(100, requires_grad=True)
t = torch.randn(2, requires_grad=True)
u = u(x,t)

# 1st derivatives
dt = torch.autograd.grad(u, t)[0]
dx = torch.autograd.grad(u, x, create_graph=True)[0]

# 2nd derivatives (higher orders require `create_graph=True`)
ddx = torch.autograd.grad(dx, x)[0]
```

Comment: Thanks, but still i am getting error.

File "C:\Users\Sunny Raghav\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch\autograd_init_.py", line 34, in _make_grads raise RuntimeError("grad can be implicitly created only for scalar outputs")

RuntimeError: grad can be implicitly created only for scalar outputs

Comment: @Sunny Your function `u()` produces multiple outputs - PyTorch's gradients are designed to work on scalar functions. You'll need to coalesce them into a single value using [e.g. `.sum()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58510249/pytorch-autograd-what-does-runtime-error-grad-can-be-implicitly-created-only-f).

Comment: I am trying to solve PDE for which i need to calculate differential wrt to t and x of u(x,t).

Comment: @Sunny I understand that - you get the error message "RuntimeError: grad can be implicitly created only for scalar outputs" when you try to call `grad` on a function outputting a tensor with multiple values (e.g. `[0,1,0,1]`), it only supports differentiation of functions which output a single value (e.g. '1.34').